# Quota limit when deploying Next.js to firebase with CLI

Tags: firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, firebase-tools

I am using the 'firebase deploy' command to deploy a Next.JS project to firebase.

When deploying functions, the command attempts to create a Cloud Run function to handle server side rendering.

I get this error.

```
!  functions: Your current project quotas don't allow for the current max instances setting of 100. Either reduce this function's maximum instances, or request a quota increase on the underlying Cloud Run service at https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas.
!  functions: You can adjust the max instances value in your function's runtime options:
        setGlobalOptions({maxInstances: 10})
Failed to update function projects/philantrho-threads/locations/europe-west1/functions/ssrphilantrhothreads

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        firebase-frameworks-philantrho-threads:ssrphilantrhothreads(europe-west1)
```

I have attempted to setGlobalOptions in the server.js file like so

```
const { onRequest } = require('firebase-functions/v2/https');
const { setGlobalOptions } = require('firebase-functions/v2/options');

  setGlobalOptions({ maxInstances: 10});
  const server = import('firebase-frameworks');
  exports.ssrphilantrhothreads = onRequest({"region":"europe-west1"}, (req, res) => server.then(it => it.handle(req, res)));
```

But when I run 'firebase deploy', the file overwrites to the default code, removing setGlobalOptions :

```
const { onRequest } = require('firebase-functions/v2/https');
  const server = import('firebase-frameworks');
  exports.ssrphilantrhothreads = onRequest({"region":"europe-west1"}, (req, res) => server.then(it => it.handle(req, res)));
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show where and how you are using `setGlobalOptions` in order to be assisted.

Comment: Edited and simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

You will want to set max instances in your `firebase.json` like so:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
 "frameworksBackend": {
      "maxInstances": 2
    }
  }
}
```

This should ensure that Cloud Run will read max instances and apply it.

Comment: Thank you! I was putting “maxInstances” under “functions” in the firebase.json. I found this link using your reply with more detail for anyone finding this thread. https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-framework-tools/blob/main/README.md